# How to add object id to end of rails path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my notifications model I have a field called `'link_path'` it spits out something like:

```
national_races/36/?notification_id=
```

When I loop through these notifications, I'm trying to append a notification ID to the end of the link path.

```
<% @x.each do |notify| %> 

<% @a = notify.id  %> 

<%= link_to notify.link_path + @a do %>
```

Hoping to end up with something like:

```
national_races/36/?notification_id=44
```

Where 44 might be the notification id. But I just keep getting:

> undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass.

Seems like I can't concatenate some string to the end of my rails route? How should I go about this?

`notify.link_path` works fine on its own, but can't get this id to pass to end of url

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from the model and controller? What does your routes file look like?

Comment: Can you show the final HTML you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I suggest you close this; it's directly related to your other link question and I think you've got an answer that works now (and that question has all the context/code of your problem anyway). Though I will say that ``NilClass`` error is probably because not all your ``notify`` objects have a ``link_path`` set.

Comment: ok will close this one

Comment: Definitely should be creating links using route definitions, not from methods in models. That way you would do something like `link_to 'some text', notification_path(@a)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below :-

**##Syntax** :-

```
<%= link_to "Link name", link_path(:foo => "bar", :baz => "quux") %>
```

According to your code :-

```
<%= link_to "Notify link path", notify.link_path(notification_id: notify.id) do %>
```

The [API docs on link_to](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) show some examples of link_to rails.